# Answering = super heroic stuff?

Tags: discussion

If a person posts a question which is little vague, an ideal response would be asking to provide additional information or should be downvoted. But instead of that, people these days are posting sarcastic comments. Should there be anything which filter out such depressed people who having high points try to always provide such comments or provide wrong feedback on question?

I have seen quite a number of people not using Stack Overflow due to these people. It is so sad for the community which was made to help the developers rather to make fun of them.

Comment: There will always be a human element (*pftt...silly humans*) and some people will be jerks. The community and it's standards try to do its best to prevent these things and there are many ways of dealing with them. However, there's no way to eliminate all of it. If you have a more concrete suggestion and possibly some examples, then feel free to bring it up here. Also remember that some of the "sarcastic comments" may be due to experienced users seeing constant questions with no effort. It isn't always just because they have a lot of points and want to show off to their "internet friends"

Comment: Some of the "sarcastic comments" are devised to help the poster *think* about the question for himself, which is always more valuable to OP than answering the question itself (the OP is supposed to show that they already did think about the question, in which case there is no need for "teaching you to think" comments)  Of course, an actual answer benefits future readers.

Comment: Just flag comments that aren't constructive. Moderators will usually delete them without a second thought.

Comment: @LaurentS. _'outright, offensively off-topic questions... damage site image no matter if there are snarky comments there or not - "hey look it's okay to dump garbage over here"....
If one worries about snarky comments in posts like that, well the real solution is simply to delete these posts - the sooner the better. Whatever comments are there will be deleted along the way, making it not an issue....'_ ([At what point are comments classified as rude or offensive for off-topic questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260782/165773))

Comment: How about you not ask lousy, vague questions and we'll stop telling you how bad they are?  Ironically, this would make **everybody** happier.  Happiness, as it does IRL, truly begins with you.

Comment: Thanks alot @Will for letting me know that my questions were vague and lousy.

Comment: And thanks a lot @BilltheLizard  for your constructive comment, appreciate your thought !!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Considering the time frames, I imagine that your question here was triggered by the comments on your [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507936/desktop-to-windows-store-application-communication) on SO. And if that's the case, I don't think you understood the situation. Let's analyze your question:

1. You say you already have an application, but you didn't post any code. Not that this automatically makes your question bad, but it's not a good starting point.
2. Then, you describe a functionality you want to implement, but again, no code (have you *tried* something already?). You say you have done some research and found some results (no links to them though), but it's not very clear why those results weren't exactly what you want.
3. You describe another functionality. Best case scenario, this should be a different question. This time you haven't found (or searched) for solutions, and you ask if it's possible, but now *how* to do it.

Then comes the first comment. The user asks *What do you have so far?*. He wants to know, precisely, your attempts so far. Where's the code? You shouldn't come here and ask people to do something, you have to try, try again, and if you fail, post your attempts and ask why it didn't work, or how it could be improved.

But you just repeated what's in your question, that you have an application and you want not one, but two new features, without apparently having written any piece of code to create them. That leads to the comment you seem to have disliked: *So, you are looking for someone to code it for you?*.

Well, I'm sorry but that's exactly what I would ask. You're not asking for a simple "*How do I write a for loop in C#?*" question, which is the type of question people will answer with code 100% written by them. I'm not a C# programmer, but what your ask for definitely doesn't sound like something trivial.

Finally, you are the one who actually comment with irony. The comments before were objective and according to the SO philosophy. They were short, yet I personally agree with them.

Now to fix your question, you could do some things:

1. Be specific. You asked for help on two different problems, but you should ask one at a time.
2. Try to create your functionality first. Start from scratch (or from your search results), and them come back with a specific doubt. I won't try to give examples related to your question because this is not my area of expertise, but ideally you'd have a piece of code that is supposed to do something specific (e.g. send a message to the client) but doesn't work (maybe it throws of an exception, maybe nothing happens).

I'm sorry to say, but your question needs improvements, nothing is wrong with what happened on that question (IMHO). And usually people won't write all of texts (like this) explaining why, they'll give simple tips as why it isn't good and unless you fix the issues, you're probably not getting an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162089/for-loop-not-executed

Above question does have a code and explained what is the problem, still down votes !!! that too for a for loop

Comment: @staticshockdracoon You're sticking to a rather minor point of this answer.

Comment: Thanks alot :) Appreciate your time .. i will try to improve on my questioning skills !!!

Comment: @staticshockdracoon: And in that case, as it was basically a typo, someone gave a comment containing the answer less than 30 seconds after the question was posted. I believe the downvotes were probably for a lack of research there - if the OP had spent a little more time trying to diagnose the issue, running in the debugger etc, they'd likely have found the problem themselves.

Comment: @staticshockdracoon that question is vomitous.  They include all the code that is not relevant at all to their question.  Their question could also be solved by debugging, something that us here, on the other side of the intertubes in different countries, **cannot do for you** (you, in the general sense, not you specifically, unless it applies).  No wonder it's downvoted and vtc'd.